# Are there any recent GMP Windows binary distributions?

Tags: windows, build, gmp

I'm looking for a recent (preferably up-to-date to the latest version) repository of binary builds of GMP for Windows.

I've only been able to find horribly outdated (+5 years) builds so far.

I can't compile GMP myself - the compilation needs too much RAM.

Comment: Do you require GMP specifically? If not, [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) is a Windows-friendly alternative, forked from GMP, which should expose more or less the same functions as GMP. By the way, doesn't this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385988/getting-gmp-libraries-to

Comment: @MihaiTodor : Unfortunately, I get wrong results with mpir.

Comment: @user2284570: Interesting. Could you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to illustrate these wrong results? I'm sure the MPIR contributors will be interested to hear of new bugs.

Comment: @MihaiTodor : There’s might be loss of money if I disclose the details. I finally tried on cygwin and got the same result as the peer checked value.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure how to help. Perhaps it might be worth trying to use Docker, now that they have a native version for Windows that doesn't even require VirtualBox to be installed. You could run any Linux version of GMP inside a container.