# Installing new C++ library to Eclipse (GMP)

Tags: c++, eclipse, libraries, gmp

I have successfully installed GMP using cygwin on my machine but I cannot figure out how to properly include the library within eclipse.  I have added the libraries within the settings, both the -l and -L options, and I have added gmp to all relevent paths and symbols tabs.  I still have an error that begins with undefined reference "__gmpz_init_set_str", and an "x" over my makefile.

I assume this means that the library is still not linked correctly but I've tried everything that I've found on the internet, both on this website and others to no avail.  This is my first time installing an external library so it could be something obvious that everyone neglects to mention that I'm missing.

I followed these instructions for cygwin, making sure that I have all the necessary things installed in cygwin and using the latest version of GMP rather than the version on this site: http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/, so that everything is configured correctly for my system.  After GMP was installed, I followed roughly these instructions ([Getting gmp libraries to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385988/getting-gmp-libraries-to)) to install it within eclipse, but with obvious changes from MinGW.  I'm pretty lost and don't know what else to try at this point.

Thanks in advance for any and all responses.

Comment: Libraries usually aren't installed particularly for Eclipse, but for your development environment.

Comment: You may have to adjust project settings to integrate a lib from your actual development environment.

Comment: OK, how would I go about adjusting the project settings from my development environment?  All I've used so far is eclipse and cygwin.

Comment: Add include/lib search path directories and linked libs to your Eclipse project.