# Using GMP with Eclipse

Tags: gmp

I used instructions at [Getting gmp libraries to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385988/getting-gmp-libraries-to)  to use GMP with Eclipse but I am getting error: `g++: error: argument to ‘-fmessage-length=’ should be a non-negative integer
make: *** [aks.o] Error 1`
while building the project. I have no idea about this error. How do I fix it?

Comment: How about removing `-fmessage-length=XXX` from whatever you did? When you follow random advice on the net, be prepared to adapt a minimum... You didn't even say at what point in these instructions you get that error (note that those instructions contain quite a bit of nonsense).

Comment: How to include GMP library then in Eclipse?